# Dato1 is not defined

Tags: python, sublimetext3, messagebox

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de python en sublime text 3 para aprender el uso de los messagebox. Es un programa muy simple donde se suma dos números y si se ingresan los dos, el título de la ventana cambia para dar el resultado y si se omite un entry, manda un mensaje donde indica el error.

El problema es que cuando corro el programa e interactuo con la ventana, me manda un error donde dice que mi variable del primer número(dato1)no está definida, he intentado mover las funciones de lugar y definir las variables dentro de la función que hace la suma, pero el error persiste, anexo el código esperando puedan ayudarme.

```
 from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
from tkinter import messagebox as mb 

root=Tk()

labelframe1=LabelFrame(root, text="Suma de números")
labelframe1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10)

def agregar_componentes():
    label1=Label(labelframe1, text="Ingrese primer valor: ")
    label1.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
    dato1=StringVar()
    entry1=Entry(labelframe1, textvariable=dato1)
    entry1.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    label2=Label(labelframe1, text="Ingrese segundo valor: ")
    label2.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="e")
    dato2=StringVar()
    entry2=Entry(labelframe1, textvariable=dato2)
    entry2.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=5, pady=5)

    boton1=Button(labelframe1, text="Sumar", command=sumar)
    boton1.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="we")

def agregar_menu():
    menubar1=Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menubar1)
    opciones1=Menu(menubar1, tearoff=0)
    opciones1.add_command(label="Acerca de...", command=acerca)
    menubar1.add_cascade(label="Opciones", menu=opciones1)

def sumar():

    if dato1.get()=="" or dato2.get()=="":
        mb.showerror("Cuidado", "No puede dejar los cuadros de entrada de numeros vacíos")
    else:
        suma=int(dato1.get())+int(dato2.get())
        root.title("La suma es "+str(suma))

def acerca():
    mb.showinfo("Información", "Este programa fue desarrollado....")


agregar_componentes()
agregar_menu()




root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

El mensaje de error `Dato1 is not defined` es claro: Esta intentando utilizar una variable que no está declarada.

En el caso concreto de su código se da porque en el metodo `sumar()` esta intentando utilizar la variable `dato1` que no esta definida dentro del cuerpo de dicho método.

La variable `dato1` la declara en el método `agregar_componentes()` pero no se está declarando global.

Para declararla global tiene que colocar antes de la por asignación `dato1=StringVar()` la siguiente linea

```
global dato1
```

para declarar la variable dato1 como global.

También debería declarar `dato2` como global

Comment: Efectivamente, aún no había tocado el tema de las variables globales pero esto arregló todo, gracias por tu ayuda